# Putting numbers in specific ranges giving out weird output

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to put my generated numbers into a specific range but it keeps giving me this output:

```
200 Generated numbers, 10 per line: 
99 Numbers from 0-20: 1
Numbers from 20-40: 0
Numbers from 40-60: 0
Numbers from 60-80: 0
Numbers from 80-100: 0
18 Numbers from 0-20: 2
Numbers from 20-40: 0
Numbers from 40-60: 0
Numbers from 60-80: 0
Numbers from 80-100: 0
56 Numbers from 0-20: 3
```

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStats2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random ();
        int[] num = new int [5];
        System.out.println("200 Generated numbers, 10 per line: ");
        int numbersOnThisLine = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            int nextNumber = random.nextInt(101);
            System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");
            numbersOnThisLine++;    

            if (numbersOnThisLine == 10){
                System.out.print("\n");
                numbersOnThisLine = 0;
            }

            if(i <=21) num[0]++;
            else if(i <=41) num[1]++;
            else if(i <=61) num[2]++;
            else if(i <=81) num[3]++;
            else if(i <=100) num[4]++;
            System.out.println("Numbers from 0-20: " + num[0]);
            System.out.println("Numbers from 20-40: " + num[1]);
            System.out.println("Numbers from 40-60: " + num[2]);
            System.out.println("Numbers from 60-80: " + num[3]);
            System.out.println("Numbers from 80-100: " + num[4]);               
        }   
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? Also, how would I set a range like 41-60 in the else if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check you nextNumber so I think you want this:

```
if(nextNumber <21){ num[0]++;}
else if(nextNumber <41){ num[1]++;}
else if(nextNumber <61){ num[2]++;}
else if(nextNumber <81){ num[3]++;}
else if(nextNumber <101){ num[4]++;}
```

Also, use these {} whenever you are working with if-else.

Second, print after the loop ended.

Comment: Using this, it would be impossible for any of the else ifs to ever be evaluated, since each of these are all checking the same condition.

Comment: Okay so I did what you told me to do, but now its printing all the numbers on the same line,

Comment: You only needed to move the range output, since it is not important to see this after every new number.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the calls to `System.out.println()` outside of your `for` loop will resolve the issue with the repeated output. Also, your current `if` and `else if` statements are not checking for the right values. Try this:

```
if (nextNumber <= 20) num[0]++;
else if (nextNumber <= 40) num[1]++;
else if (nextNumber <= 60) num[2]++;
else if (nextNumber <= 80) num[3]++;
else if (nextNumber <= 100) num[4]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really supposed to do all of that inside of the for loop? I am not sure of what you are trying to accomplish, but a wild suggestion is to print it out outside of the loop.

Right now you are printing what you have found for every random integer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you want to print out the ranges every 10th iteration. If so, move your print statements inside the if statement as below.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStats2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random ();
        int[] num = new int [5];
        System.out.println("200 Generated numbers, 10 per line: ");
        int numbersOnThisLine = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            int nextNumber = random.nextInt(101);
            System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");
            numbersOnThisLine++;    

            if (numbersOnThisLine == 10){
                System.out.print("\n");
                numbersOnThisLine = 0;
                System.out.println("Numbers from 0-20: " + num[0]); 
                System.out.println("Numbers from 20-40: " + num[1]);
                System.out.println("Numbers from 40-60: " + num[2]);
                System.out.println("Numbers from 60-80: " + num[3]);
                System.out.println("Numbers from 80-100: " + num[4]);
            }

            if(i <=21) num[0]++;
            else if(i <=41) num[1]++;
            else if(i <=61) num[2]++;
            else if(i <=81) num[3]++;
            else if(i <=100) num[4]++;            
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your statistics needs to be out of the for loop like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

public class RandomStats2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random ();
    int[] num = new int [5];
    System.out.println("200 Generated numbers, 10 per line: ");
    int numbersOnThisLine = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        int nextNumber = random.nextInt(101);
        System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");
        numbersOnThisLine++;    

        if (numbersOnThisLine == 10){
            System.out.print("\n");
            numbersOnThisLine = 0;
        }

        if(i <=21) num[0]++;
        else if(i <=41) num[1]++;
        else if(i <=61) num[2]++;
        else if(i <=81) num[3]++;
        else if(i <=100) num[4]++;              
    }   
    System.out.println("Numbers from 0-20: " + num[0]);
    System.out.println("Numbers from 20-40: " + num[1]);
    System.out.println("Numbers from 40-60: " + num[2]);
    System.out.println("Numbers from 60-80: " + num[3]);
    System.out.println("Numbers from 80-100: " + num[4]); 
}
```

}

Also for the if statements i think you meant to use `nextNumber`and not `i`, since `i` is you loop counter